# Twitter Reverse Auth information

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am requesting Reverse Auth permission from Twitter for iOS5+.

While getting Reverse Auth permission at https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform, it asks for several information.

What i need to fill for Application ID and Application URL in this form so i can get access token value for twitter API?

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Twitter app: https://dev.twitter.com/apps this will provide you with an application ID. The URL is just the website for your app.